# How to use foreach in c++ cli in managed code

Tags: c++-cli

Hi how to use foreach loop in managed code c++ using vs2003.

Comment: And I just found this fantastic tidbit on Jochen Kalmbach's blog: the hidden $I variable holds the current index of the iteration. http://blog.kalmbach-software.de/2009/12/30/the-mystic-variable-i-during-for-each/

Answer (score 46):

I've never used it, but [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202(VS.80).aspx) indicates the general syntax is just:

```
for each(Type t in IEnumerable)
{

}
```

Comment: It's the same as C# but with a space between for and each.

Comment: in VS2005 it is ok bur in VS2003 it gives erroe.i dont know y it behaves like that.

Comment: Cute, because it's new in Visual C++ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw(VS.80).aspx), not to be confused with Managed Extensions for C++.

Comment: This is kind of a old question, but this should still be working in VS 2022, right? I get a red line under `each` that says, "expected a '('" and then another under `in` that says, "expected a ';'". Am I missing a using statement or an include? I'm just trying to iterate over an IEnumerable in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 17):

Matthew is mostly correct, but here's a working block of code;

```
///////
array<Type^>^ iterate_me = gcnew array<Type^>(2);
iterate_me[0] = Type::GetType("Type");
iterate_me[1] = Type::GetType("System.Int32");
///////

for each(Type^ t in iterate_me)
    Console::WriteLine(t);
```

The changes were Type is a reference class, so you use "Type^" not "Type" and you need an actual object reference (iterate_me)...

Comment: Managed C++ in VS 2003 is unfortunately quite different from C++.NET that was introduced in VS 2005+. There was no `for each` block. **Managed C++** should absolutely be avoided. C++.NET is fine for use.

Comment: Ahhh right, the title confused me, it read's "c++ cli ..." I glossed over the part where he was asking about 2003.

Comment: Not a big deal. Just wanted to make sure anyone finding this from Google/Bing doesn't go down the dark path of Managed C++ development.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
String ^ MyString = gcnew String("abcd");

for each ( Char c in MyString )

    Console::Write(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of VS2022 `for each` apparently no longer works. Instead you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerator^ enumerator = myList->GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator->MoveNext())
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -9):

I don't think that VC++ has foreach

Comment: well, there is std::for_each, and Boost.Foreach, and normal for loops, so I really don't think you are quite right there

Comment: I don't believe any of those apply automatically to IEnumerable.

Comment: They certainly won't take care of disposing the IEnumerable.